Stripe payment_methods list empty array
Stripe cli command stripe payment_methods list returns empty array even I have 9 active payment methods in Stripe admin dashboard.
I'm sure that I'm using correct api_key for stripe cli.
Not sure if I'm doing something wrong. I need that list in order to display available payment option for customers on frontend.
stripe payment_methods list

{
  "object": "list",
  "data": [],
  "has_more": false,
  "url": "/v1/payment_methods"
}

Stripe admin dashboard


What you're looking at on the dashboard is the available payment method types for your account. What the Stripe CLI command is returning is the PaymentMethods created.

how then I can get list of payment methods that are available to customer. I have UI where user can add/remove or update it's payment methods. So user in settings will be able to add own payment method (based on list that stripe admin defined) and later using saved payment method pay for subscription. I'm not sure if that UI flow is possible to implement with stripe?

You can list a customer's payment methods by using this API method.
To save payments methods for future usage you can take a look at this guide
